# Is there a Pytest equivalent to the unittest unittest.TestLoader.loadTestsFromModule() method?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, abstract-syntax-tree

I am working on a program that modifies test suites.
In the original implementation, there was only support for the `unittest` framework. I am trying to add support for Pytest now.

With the default `unitest` module, I could keep the modified tests as ASTs in memory, which I convert to a module, and finally, I can create a test suite from that, and run it.

```py
#create module
code = test.AST.compile()
module = types.ModuleType(test.name)
module.__dict__.update(scope)
exec(code, module.__dict__)
#create suite
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(module)
#run test
suite.run()
```

From everything that I can find in the Pytest documentation, this seems not possible.
Pytest needs the testfiles to function.

Does someone know if this is either possible for Pytest or a possible workaround? I don't want to write hundredths of modified tests to the filesystem, as this would be more expensive than keeping them in memory.

Comment: You should be able to run test modules written using `unittest` with pytest, if there is no way to create such a structure in pytest framework.

Comment: I am trying to add support for the Pytest framework to my program, so the tests are written for Pytest.

This was not entirely clear from my original question. Going to edit it so it's more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so thanks to lead developer [nicoddemus](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/discussions/9138#discussioncomment-1410084) I have found the answer, I've decided to share it also here.

The gist of it is as follows:
From inside my program I still create the module in memory as above, and I push the module on the stack. Next, I call pytest with `pytest.main`:

```py
# Create Module
code = test.AST.compile()
module = types.ModuleType(test.name)
module.__dict__.update(scope)
exec(code, module.__dict__)

modules.append(module)
# Run test
result = pytest.main([test.filename, "-p", "inject_module"])
```

In `inject_module.py` I have defined the following hook, which simply performs the default logic, but sets the `_obj` attribute of the `Module` to my module on the stack.

```py
def pytest_pycollect_makemodule(path, parent) -> "Module":
    if path.basename == "__init__.py":
        pkg: Package = Package.from_parent(parent, fspath=path)
        return pkg
    mod: Module = Module.from_parent(parent, fspath=path)
    mod._obj = modules.pop()
    return mod
```